# Unicornify on meta should include a token waffle

Tags: discussion, fun, waffles

The unicornify script on meta is **broken**

At the bare minimum it should include 1 token waffle in the image.

I mean come on!

Comment: Don't forget the hand-drawn circle

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Please!

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that there is a waffle keyboard on the [page not found](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/pagenotfound) page?